# Fatal error when trying to play audio in Swift

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

Trying to play audio but keep receiving `fatal error`:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie", ofType: "mp3"){
            var filePathURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
            var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathURL!, error: nil)

        }else{
            println("the filePath is empty")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func playSlowAudio(sender: UIButton) {
        //play sloooowly
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `var filePathURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)` is returning nil, wrapped in an Optional. Then on the next line `filePathURL!` forces the Optional to unwrap, resulting in `nil` and giving the error you see.

You should check to make sure the `filePath` is correct for the file you are trying to load. Make sure the file is in your bundle and that you typed the file name correctly. Setting a breakpoint there and debugging would probably be helpful.

Also, to be safer, you may want to change the if statement so `NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)` is part of the `if`:

```
if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie", ofType: "mp3"),
   let filePathURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath) {
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathURL, error: nil)

}else{
    println("the filePath is empty OR the file did not load")
}
```

Also note: I used `let` instead of `var` for the variables in the `if` statement so they are constants. It is good practice to use `let` when you can.