# Getting a fatal error when trying to play sound in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, avaudioplayer

I have worked my way through this tutorial [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/114298/learn-to-code-ios-apps-with-swift-tutorial-5-making-it-beautiful). One of the last things you do is have a button make sound when it is pressed. I wanted to then continue using that same logic to make a sound board app. However when I stripped the non-essential parts besides it making noise inside a new project I started getting a fatal error.

Here is my ViewController.swfit file:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation



class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var sample : AVAudioPlayer?

func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file:NSString, type:NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer?  {
    //1
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

    //2
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

    // 3
    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    } catch {
        print("Player not available")
    }

    return audioPlayer
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let sample = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("Stomach", type:"aif") {
        self.sample = sample
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed()  {
    sample?.play()
}


}
```

Here is my project when the fatal error hits

[image]

I have also tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29731558/2117460) but I got errors as well.

I am running on El Capitan 10.11.3 with Xcode 7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you included the an audio file named "Stomach.aif" in your project? If not, `pathForResource` will return nil and you'll crash when attempting to force unwrap that path. You can use a safer version of this function, although if it can't locate that file it still won't play the audio On the bright side it shouldn't crash.

```
func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file:NSString, type:NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer?  {
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer? = nil

    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String) {
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)

        do {
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        } catch {
            print("Player not available")
        }
    }

    return audioPlayer
}
```

Comment: Good news and bad news. This works and doesn't crash the app (yay!). However, I do have the audio file copied into my project but it still is not playing it. I am gonna work on it more to see if its an error I made in the button pressing part. But that func seems to work

Comment: It works! Turns out .aif is not supported. Used an .mp3 and it worked great. Thanks so much!